# Next-Auth ClientFetching Error (potentially cors issue)

Tags: next-auth

I am using next-auth with the google provider on localhost.

I have a simple sign in button which looks like this:

```
       <button onClick={() => signIn('google')}>Sign in with Google </button>
```

When I click the button I receive the following error message:

[image]

Here is my api/auth/[...nextauth].ts route:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

console.log(process.env.Google_ID as string);
console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string);

export const authOptions = {
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            clientSecret: 'XXXXX',
        }),
    ],
    secret: 'secret',
    debug: true,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

My local env file (.env.local) contains `NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000`.

My nextjs-config is also untouched and looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I spent a couple of hours debugging already and looked through 30+ SO answers but couldn't find anything that solved the issue.